# Using of "line," in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I don't understand the purpose of the comma in the following script after the word "line".

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [0,1]
y = [0,1]
line, = plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

i have tried to understand it in the [official documentation website](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-pyplot-py) but without success

Comment: @cdarke is correct. I'm not sure why the plot method returns any value, perhaps the intention was to get the results of interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

A comma on the left side of an assignment creates a tuple.  For example:

```
a, b = [123, 456]
```

`a` will refer to `123` and `b` will refer to `456`.

`matplotlib.pyplot.plot` returns a list of lines (as `Line2D` objects) that were added.

In your case `plt.plot(x, y)` returns a single element list since it only adds one line, but the comma is still required to create the tuple:

```
line, = plt.plot(x, y)
```

will take the first element from the returned list.  If there is more then one element then the assignment will fail with `too many values to unpack`.  If you omit the comma then `line` becomes a `list` rather than a single `Line2D` object.

Most people would write this way instead:

```
line = plt.plot(x, y)[0]
```

That is, indexing the returned list.  If there is more than one element then this will not fail, but sometimes failures are good - it depends on what you need.